# How do I make a Wicket Panel hidden?

Tags: java, wicket, panel

So I have to edit code of a co-worker but I cannot seem to figure out how to adjust it so the panel is hidden when there is no data present. Currently it returns null when no data is present. If there is information available for a customer, it shows their full info. If there is not, I want to make the panel hidden. This is also a re-useable panel used throughout the site. What do I need to adjust to make this work?

```
@Override
protected void onInitialize()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onInitialize();        


    if(customer != null)
    {
        loadWithCustomer();
    }
    else
    {
        loadWithNoCustomer();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() 
{
    super.onBeforeRender();

    AjaxLink<Void> createOrderLink = makeCreateOrderLink(customer);

    SkinnyBuSession session = (SkinnyBuSession) Session.get();      
    if(session != null && session.getCustomer() == null)
        createOrderLink.setEnabled(false);

    addOrReplace(createOrderLink);
}

private void loadWithCustomer()
{
    addOrReplace(new Label("heading",  customer.getAccountName()));


    Contact contact = null;
    if( customer.getContacts() != null && customer.getContacts().size() > 0)
    {
        contact = customer.getContacts().get(0);
    }
    else
    {
        contact = new Contact();//makeUpJunkContactForNow();
        customer.getContacts().add(contact);
    }
    Address address = null;
    if( customer.getAddresses() != null && customer.getAddresses().size() > 0)
    {
        address = customer.getAddresses().get(0);
    }
    else
    {
        address = new Address();//makeUpJunkAddressForNow();
        customer.getAddresses().add(address);
    }

    String phone = contact.getPhoneNumber() != null ? contact.getPhoneNumber().getNationalNumber() : "";
    if (phone != null && phone.length() == 10)
    {
        phone = String.format("(%s) %s-%s", phone.substring(0, 3), phone.substring(3, 6),phone.substring(6, 10));
    }       

    addOrReplace(new Label("accountName", customer.getAccountName()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("address1", address.getAddressLine1()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("address2", address.getAddressLine2()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("city", address.getCityName() + ","));
    addOrReplace(new Label("state", address.getStateCode()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("postalCode", address.getPostalCode()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("contactName", contact.getName()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("email", contact.getEmailAddress()));
    addOrReplace(new Label("phone", phone));        

}

private void loadWithNoCustomer()
{
    Label heading = new Label("heading", "");
    addOrReplace(heading.setVisible(false));

    addOrReplace(new Label("accountName", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("address1", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("address2", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("city", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("state", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("postalCode", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("contactName", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("email", "").setVisible(false));
    addOrReplace(new Label("phone", "").setVisible(false));

}
```

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried already.

Answer (score 3):

Override onConfigure and you can probably do something like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onConfigure() {
     super.onConfigure();
     setVisible(customer != null);
}
```

Comment: You need to use setVisibilityAllowed, as the component may override the isVisible() method, ignoring the value you set with setVisible()